# Can't create file in python filesystem

Tags: python, filesystems

I have this school project to create a virtual filesystem using python. I want to create an add method does not do anything at all.

```
import shelve
import sys

fs = shelve.open('filesystem.fs', writeback=True)
current_dir = []

def install(fs):

# create root and others
username = raw_input('What do you want your username to be? ')

fs[""] = {"System": {}, "Users": {username: {}}}

def current_dictionary():
"""Return a dictionary representing the files in the current directory"""
d = fs[""]
for key in current_dir:
    d = d[key]
return d 

def ls(args):

print 'Contents of directory', "/" + "/".join(current_dir) + ':'

for i in current_dictionary():

    print i

def cd(args):

if len(args) != 1:

    print "Usage: cd "
    return

if args[0] == "..":
    if len(current_dir) == 0:
        print "Cannot go above root"
    else:
        current_dir.pop()
elif args[0] not in current_dictionary():
    print "Directory " + args[0] + " not found"
else:
    current_dir.append(args[0])

def mkdir(args):
if len(args) != 1:
    print "Usage: mkdir "
    return

#To create an empty directory there and sync back to shelve dictionary!

d = current_dictionary()[args[0]] = {}
fs.sync()

def pwd(args):

d=current_dir
print d[-1]

def quit(args):
sys.exit(0)

def add(args):
with open("test.txt", 'w') as f:
    f.write("test")

COMMANDS = {'ls' : ls, 'cd': cd, 'mkdir': mkdir,'pwd':pwd,'quit':quit,'add':add}

install(fs)

while True:
raw = raw_input('> ')
cmd = raw.split()[0]
if cmd in COMMANDS:
    COMMANDS[cmd](raw.split()[1:])
```

My problem is this method does not do anything. I just want it to create a file in the directory that is active.

```
def add(args):
with open("test.txt", 'w') as f:
    f.write("test")
```

Comment: Please format this correctly.

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions? Are you calling the function?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe include the `current_dir` path when you open the file?

```
full_path = '/'.join(current_dir + ["test.txt"])
with open(full_path, "w") as f:
    f.write("test")
```

Comment: Maybe use `os.path.join`

Comment: I tried that but because the file does not exist i get this error

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Users/mo/test.txt'

any way it can create a file if it doesn't exist?

Comment: Your path must exist first.  `Users/mo` is from your current path.