# Cannot save dictionary to the file

Tags: python, json, dictionary, save

I am working on a simple script and Im having troubles to save my dict output from the server to the file. There are no errors but the data is not being saved to the file. Could you help?

```
s=requests.Session()

response = s.post("https://tp-dc-ixm0.net/api/login", verify=False, data=user_passwd)

response1 = json.loads(s.get("https://tp-dc-ixm0.net/api/tests?status=all&topology=NodeToNode&limit=100", verify=False, data=user_passwd).text)

print(type(response1))
with open('data.txt', 'w') as output:
    json.dump(response1, output)
```

Comment: So, what does `data.txt` contain?

Comment: I tried your code and it worked. Is `response1` not empty? May you try to print it too?

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
import json
with open('data.txt', 'w') as output:
    output.write(json.dumps(response1))
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. Same. No errors but not able to save to the file. And the data is for sure there. When I print it there's a bunch of data.

Answer (score 0):

[Try this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/json-dump-in-python/)

```
import json
  
# python object(dictionary) to be dumped
dict1 ={
    "emp1": {
        "name": "Lisa",
        "designation": "programmer",
        "age": "34",
        "salary": "54000"
    },
    "emp2": {
        "name": "Elis",
        "designation": "Trainee",
        "age": "24",
        "salary": "40000"
    },
}
  
# the json file where the output must be stored
out_file = open("myfile.json", "w")
  
json.dump(dict1, out_file)
  
out_file.close()
```

Or this

```
with open('myfile.json', 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(d, json_file)
```

If the file is still not created, check if the program can create files in this path. Try running it as a root user or check your user rights in the folder where the file should be created.

[Permissions in linux](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/permissions-in-linux/)

Comment: Why indent 6? The standard is 4. Furthermore, you should use with statement, it is easier to manage error with :)

Comment: Thanks. Not sure why but the file with the mode "w" should be created automatically but it doesn't in both cases :/

Comment: This is an example. Well, a person does not think asynchronously, but synchronously. Why do something more personal when you can just open and close?

Comment: @Patryk-Petryszen

Does your program have access to create files?

Comment: @Doumor good point. How do I check it? I previously done similar things and never had to grant the access

Comment: @Doumor From PEP 8: `When a resource is local to a particular section of code, use a with statement to ensure it is cleaned up promptly and reliably after use. A try/finally statement is also acceptable`. It is easier and safer to use it, you will not forget to close a file before a return for example.

Comment: @PatrykPetryszen is your file created but empty or not even created? Can you try to create it with an unix / windows command like `touch data.txt`?

Comment: @Ankirama At the same time, there will be less clutter of spaces in the code. The code will be more synchronous.

Comment: @Doumor you were right! I moved the script to my Desktop and now it worked without any issues... Previously I used the path /users/patryk/... How can I grant the permission for writing files?

Comment: @PatrykPetryszen Run as a user who can create files on this path. In general, if you are on Linux, give your user in that folder write permissions.

Comment: @Doumor I have write permission in this folder. I can create and delete files :/

Comment: @PatrykPetryszen [Try full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36024541/cant-create-file-in-python-filesystem)